# mismatched tag. Expected: </br>

Tags: html

so I get this error when I load my html onto a container.

```
mismatched tag. Expected: </br>.
```

when I open it, it just points to a div tag (line 17). I have no idea what's going on, can anybody explain what's happening?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br>
<div class="panel.group" id="accordion">
 <div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
       <h3 class="panel-title">
         <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">Končani Projekti</a>
         </h3>
  </div>
      <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
       <div class="panel-body">        
    <img src="images/knjiznica-screenshot-thumbnail.jpg" class="img-thumbnail" id="knjiznica-IJS-link" alt="knjiznica webpage" />
    <h5 class="accordion-text-heading">Prenova domače spletne strani knjižnice IJS</h5>
    <br>
    <img src="images/grafi-screenshot-thumbnail.jpg" class="img-thumbnail" id="grafi-IJS-link" alt="javascript graf IJS" />
    <h5 class="accordion-text-heading">Interaktivni grafi</h5>
    <p>Spletna stran s strežnika prebere .csv datoteke, ter iz njih naredi interaktivni graf. Možnost izbire katero datoteko odpira, prisotnost vrednosti na grafu(klik na legendo). Zaradi varnosti podatkov so imena podjetij ter ustanov spremenjena v angleške števnike.</p>
       </div>
      </div>
 </div>
   <div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
       <h3 class="panel-title">
         <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">Trenutni Projekti</a>
         </h3>
  </div>
      <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
       <div class="panel-body">
          <h5 class="accordion-text-heading">- jadijada</h5>   
         </div>
      </div>
 </div> 
</div>

<script>
 $("#knjiznica-IJS-link").click(function() {
  window.open('http://topdeckandwreck.com/knjiznica%20IJS_table/public_html/Defsi.html');
 });
 $("#grafi-IJS-link").click(function() {
  window.open('http://topdeckandwreck.com/grafiIJS/');
 });
</script>
```

Comment: used br /, now it says "junk after document element" and points to line 2 xD

Comment: What browser are you using?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are probably using the xhtml doctype. For that you need to close the `<br>` tag like any other xml tag. Have a try using `<br />` instead of `<br>`.

Comment: ok thanks, this solved the error, now I'm getting junk after document element, but I guess that's unrelated, will accept solution once I can